# Using subquery instead of a table name in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Instead of:

```
 select * from Clients;
```

I am trying:

```
select * from (select tableName from CSTable where uid=1);
```

It does not work. Any suggestions?.

Just for the record

```
sqlite> .schema CSTable
CREATE TABLE CSTable (
    uid integer NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CSTable_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    tableName text NOT NULL,
);
```

And the contents of the CSTable:

```
select * from CSTable;
uid         tableName      
----------  -------------  
1           Clients
```

Comment: `uid` is  not selected in `sub-select` so you cannot select `uid` in outer query

Comment: You need dynamic SQL to do this.

Comment: You want to select uid or table name?

Comment: @Chetan I just want to query: select * from clients;